# How to remove all text after a specific character in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question relates to Excel.

I am trying to remove all text to the left of a specific character in a cell using a formula, but I keep getting an error.

I have a list of users in my website database, and I exported the email field like the following:

```
name@abc.com
joe@123.com
pete@mail.com
geor-b@me.com
```

I want to remove everything to the left of the @ symbol so that on each persons profile, I can display `@abc.com` after their full name.

I tried a number of formulas and the following seems to be the one which I should be using:

```
RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1)+1)
```

or maybe

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1)+2,256)
```

However, none of these work and Excel keeps telling me "We found a problem with this formula".
Can anybody tell me what's going wrong? I am using the latest version of Excel.

Comment: This `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1)+1)` works for me...

Comment: simply replace Like this: Step1) ctrl+H Step2) find what: *@   Step3) replace with:<Empty Field>

Answer (score 2):

If your email address is in a1 then this will work

=MID(A1,FIND("@",A1,1),LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1,1)+1)

Comment: Note that you can safely tell the MID function to pick up more characters than there are remaining - it simply ignores the extras. Also, FIND does not require the starting location to be named if it is "1". So this could be simplified to: =MID(A1,FIND("@",A1),LEN(A1))    Technically you are saying "start where you find the @, and go for the entire length of the cell [which is now too long for the remaining length], but instead Excel simply stops at the end of the cell.

Comment: OMG!!! I realised why my first function would not work.... I had previously changed the system settings for the coma delimeter and changed it to ';'.  (I did this so I could open a csv file properly).  However, your function works perfect. thanks.